# Is it possible to do a bulk search in AWS CloudSearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

For example I would like to send my domain an array of strings `['car', 'bus', 'plane']` and return match results for each string in the array.

I know that ElasticSearch has this capability, but I couldn't find anything on SO or the docs for CloudSearch.